# SASS Simple function to convert HEX color into RGB as a string without alpha

Tags: css, sass, colors

I am looking for simple function in SASS that simply convert HEX color into RGB as a string.
I was googling, but without lucky. Maybe because there is not any native function in SASS? Sure, there is `rgba()` function, but I dont wanna `rgba(` ... `)` piece. Simply the RGB string.

## Example

### Input

```
$color-bg: #637b9a;
$color-bg-light: lighten($color-bg, 25%);
$color-bg-light-rgb: hex2rgb($color-bg-light); // Functon that I am looking for

:root {
  --color-body-bg-light: $color-bg-light;
  --color-body-bg-light-rgb: $color-bg-light-rgb;
}
body {
  color: var(--color-body-bg-light);
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-body-bg-light-rgb), 0.8);
}
```

### Output

```
:root {
  --color-body-bg-light: #237b9a;
  --color-body-bg-light-rgb: 44, 123, 154;
}

body {
  color: var(--color-body-bg-light);
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-body-bg-light-rgb), 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the function like this:

```
@use "sass:color";
@function hex2rgb($hex) {
  @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex);
}
```

But the problem is sass could not parse the variables for html custom properties.
So this line `--color-body-bg-light: $color-bg-light;` won't work.

At the end, you will get this:

```
:root {
  --color-body-bg-light: $color-bg-light;
  --color-body-bg-light-rgb: $color-bg-light-rgb;
}
```

Comment: I believe you can use interpolation to make it work with CSS variables. So you'll write it like this:
`--color-body-bg-light-rgb: #{$color-bg-light-rgb};`. And you the css output should contain the `r, g, b` numbers.

Comment: I believe you can use interpolation to make it work with CSS variables. So you'll write it like this:
`--color-body-bg-light-rgb: #{$color-bg-light-rgb};`. And you the css output should contain the `r, g, b` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with **Sass** but you can use **JavaScript** to get the desired result.